# I just asked a stupid question caused by a mistake of mine, do I delete?

Tags: discussion

I just asked [this question about Long Pressing on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17300882/long-press-fire-after-certain-interval-instead-of-release). I had attempted to create an OnLongClickListener but had accidentally made a regular OnClickListener. When it understandably didn't work as I intended, I came to SO. The first answer pointed out that mistake.

Do I delete this question since it was asked on false pretenses? The core of my question is non-existent. Long presses work the way I wanted them to, I just wasn't using a long press.

For now I have flagged it for mod attention since it may need to be closed instead of deleted.

Comment: Meh, it could perhaps be closed as "too localized". But then again I can see this happen to others as well. I'd personally leave it in place.

Comment: @Corey in this particular case, your question may bring awareness to other users to be careful about which listener to use.

Comment: Of course, you can always just delete your own question....

Comment: @lnafziger Except that you can't if there is an answer with a score of 1 or more...

Answer (score 11):

Well, as long as it is useful to others, leave it be.

The primary purpose of SO is not to get your questions answered (still important though), it is to create a repository of good, useful, Q&As. Your question's role on this site does not end once your problem has been solved. In fact, it's real role starts here: helping anonymous visitors from the Internet.

Of course, if your post is too localized, it may get closed and deleted. I'm not too familiar with the topic to be able to judge that.

Comment: I'm not sure my question (in retrospect) is good or useful. That opinion may be up to other users who may or may not repeat my mistakes. I hardly seeing my question being useful now that I've realized my mistake. I've voted to close my own question as too localized.

Comment: I'd consider it to be essentially the same as a typo question, and the universal rule seems to be they're always too localized (so should be closed as such and deleted).